# 'selector' is not a known element from Angular Library

Tags: angular, module, components

I created component in Angular Library and that component is included to library module. When I publish library to npm server then in project where I installed that library and import library module to app module of project then I tried to set component from library with  but I got error:

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'selector' is not a known element:

1. If 'selector' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'selector' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: So you have a component called <selector>.. ? This error usually means that the component itself is not exported correctl from the lib.

Comment: so could you tell me what is correctly way for exporting ?

Comment: It kinda depends on your module setup and how you’ve packaged your lib. It not only has to be exported from the module declaration, but also from the api export file. And when you use it, import and declare the component itself (not just the module as an import) from your package. Loads of guesswork here, hard to tell without looking at your setup.

Comment: Could you share any example ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Angular automatically detects when unknown elements are used. To prevent this from happening, you have two options:

1. You do what the error says and add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to your module or to your component:

   ```js
   @NgModule({
     schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA] // Add this
   })
   export class MyModule { }
   ```

   The downside is that this basically disables the entire check. So not only will it allow the values within the `selector`, but also any other value.
2. Another solution, which is also mentioned in a related [GitHub issues](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11251#issuecomment-244255512) is to create a custom empty directive for your selectors. For example:

   ```js
   @Directive({
     selector: 'the-selector-i-want-to-use' // TODO: Change this
   })
   export class TheSelectorIWantToUseDirective { // TODO: Change this
     // No behaviour
     // This fixes Angular's custom element detection
     // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11251#issuecomment-244255512
   }
   ```